# Flush a single entity doesn't update relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Passing an entity to the flush() method allow Doctrine to only update this entity, which is great for optimization. But it seems that the relations are not updated when I'm doing this.

Example :

```
    $event->getEmails()->first()->setEmail('mynewemail@email.com');
    $em->flush($event); // Emails wont be updated
    $em->flush(); // Emails will be updated
```

The mapping:

```
class Event
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|Email[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Email", mappedBy="event", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id"="asc"})
     */
    protected $emails;
```

I checked inside Doctrine code, and here is what I found : internally, when I flush a single entity, the method `computeSingleEntityChangeSet` is called. The comment above this method is the following:

```
/**
 * Only flushes the given entity according to a ruleset that keeps the UoW consistent.
 *
 * 1. All entities scheduled for insertion, (orphan) removals and changes in collections are processed as well!
 * 2. Read Only entities are skipped.
 * 3. Proxies are skipped.
 * 4. Only if entity is properly managed.
 * ...
 */
```

According to first rule, changes in collections are processed as well. So am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug of Doctrine?

Comment: I've come across this with Bi-directional associations only. I remember reading in the Docs (or somewhere) that the cascade will only work for associations if they are uni-directional.

Comment: I've generally found the single-entity flush to be unreliable and have moved away from it.

Comment: and that's why `flush` call with a single entity should be deprecated,  https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6118 it can't manage entity when cascade operation are involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `$event->getEmails()->first()->setEmail('mynewemail@email.com');` you're not updating the collection, but one Entity in the collection. It's normal that the single entity flush does not update the `Email` entity.

If you do write `$event->addEmail($aNewEmailEntity);` (same with remove), then you'll see that the collection is indeed updated when calling the single entity flush.

Comment: Okay it makes sense, the PHPDoc was not really clear. Thank you :)